# How is the tax gap estimated?

Tags: econometrics, taxation

I am looking at various definition of the tax gap. For instance the [IRS](https://www.irs.gov/statistics/irs-the-tax-gap):

"The gross tax gap is the difference between true tax liability for a given tax year and the amount that is paid on time"

or [EU](https://taxation-customs.ec.europa.eu/system/files/2022-12/vat-gap-factsheet-final.pdf)  for VAT:

"The VAT GAP is the overall difference between the expected VAT revenue and the amount actually collected":

While the amount of collected tax is known, I wonder how it is possible to compute/estimate the "true tax liability" since a lot of tax evasion is done trough non recorded commercial exchange.